# How to add row show name of an cell and group that cell by its name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query

```
SELECT billid, prdname, date 
FROM billdetail
```

returns this result set:

[image]

But I want to show it like this instead:

[image]

Please give me a suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: You should do that in the report, the query is the same either way. In SSRS, you can group on the prdname column and use the "stepped" grouping to see the results in your format.

Comment: Show where? Looks like UI issue not sql.

Comment: oh, it's mean i can't show it at Query result window at SQL Server right?

Comment: @Tiến Hiệu: Correct.